# What would cause a #BLOCKED! error when i copy an excel file to my computer

Tags: excel-formula, formula

I copied a excel file from 1 computer to another at my office today.  I'm using Office16.

I was looking at a formula **=Column(SheetNames)** that told me there were 16 sheets.

SheetNames is a named range   **=REPLACE(GET.WORKBOOK(1),1,FIND("]",GET.WORKBOOK(1)),"")**

But when i enter the formula bar and/or press CTRL ALT F9 to recalculate it shows #BLOCKED!  What could be causing this please.  It is not doing this on the original computer.

I don't get this problem when redo the formula and range name in another file so i suspect there must be something within the original file causing the problem.

Regards Peter

Comment: what did you learn when you googled "Excel #BLOCKED! error"? Are there any aspects on the Microsoft support page documenting the error that you couldn't follow?

Answer (score 2):

`Get` is an old XLM macro language command. These may be blocked on the machine you are using.

From the [Microsoft documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-blocked-error-13be117b-92e4-400a-a215-aa59d37d6e7c) about the #BLOCKED! error:

> Functions with XLM macros are blocked Functions with Excel 4.0 (XLM)
> macros can't be evaluated for one or more of the following reasons:
>
> Excel 4.0 (XLM) macros are turned off because of macro settings.
>
> Excel 4.0 (XLM) macros aren't supported in current version of Excel.
>
> For more information, see Working with Excel 4.0 macros.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your organization has not mandated they be turned off, Excel 4 macros can be enabled by selecting:

1. "File" from the Ribbon menuing system
2. Selecting "Options" at the bottom of the bar on the left that higher up has things like "Open" and "Print"
3. Selecting the last area on the list (also somehow not a menu any more than the Ribbon is...) called "Trust Center"
4. Clicking the button at the lower right of the text in the panel to the right labelled "Trust Center Settings"
5. Selecting "Macro Settings" from the panel on the left (again, still not a menu...)
6. Clicking "Enable Excel 4.0 macros when VBA macros are enabled"
   **AND**
7. Making sure VBA macros ARE enabled in the choices provided above

No guarantee that your organization's IP folks haven't found a choice in the Group Policy Editor that turns off your ability to set this up.

Sadly, Excel has not seen fit to provide an in-cell formula to replace `GET.WORKBOOK` so I cannot offer a substitute.

Since you have the formula in a Named Range, and so all uses in the workbook presumably refer to the Name Range, and all you need do is modify the Named Range, a single step, sort of, in order to spread a new approach into the spreadsheet, an alternative suggests itself. If your organization allows, it should not be hard at all to write the corresponding VBA function into a UDF that you can then reference in the Named Range's formula instead.

However...

It seems likely the "proximate cause" of your current problem is simply the computer you transferred the file to has Excel 4.0 macros turned off. It works on yours so they are turned on on yours and so presumably your organization allows the use of macros, or at least does not forbid them.

But since the problem occurred, it seems it is hit or miss for every computer whether macros (definitely Excel 4.0 macros, and probably also VBA macros) aare turned on or not on any given machine.

Accordingly, subject to your personal knowledge of the personalities of their users, it seems the best approach would be to get each computer owner you send the file to to activate Excel 4.0 macros on their computers as ANY choice, even VBA, would seem to require that conversation, or a similar discussion concerning VBA, take place.

(As an aside, the funny thing is usually when Excel 4.0 macros come up, people go on about you not really wanting an antiquated system in use that MS says they might trash any old time, and that you should replace what it does with some nice VBA macro instead (assuming there is no nice cell-side function provided nowadays, of course). Except, you know, they've been saying that for 20 years now. And VBA stopped developing in something like 2006. So it is antiquated on the same scale the Excel 4.0 macros are antiquated...

No question VBA is better. Just... it's as antique now as the Excel 4.0 macros so... c'mon folks.)